# Got stuck in a OnPostResume loop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an activity that loads and displays data fetched from a web service.

While the activity is fetching data, it will show a progress dialog.

Now, on this activity, there is a button that will open a new activity, to edit the data. What I want is, after I edit the data, the EditActivity finish(), and the screen will display an updated data (after fetching the data again).

So, I put the fetchData() method in onPostResume() of the first activity. The problem is, everytime the progress dialog is dismissed, it triggers onPostResume() as well. So, I am stuck in a loop.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Okay, so using onActivityResult() fixes that!

New problem though, what if the views that I want to update is in a fragment? I tried using onActivityResult, but it does nothing!

Comment: Start the `EditActivity` with `startActivityForResult()`, and call `fetchData()` in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: where is you code can you show it. so its easy to help you. and u have use `onResume()` for this

Comment: Please try searching the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment Also, one post, one question. Don't change what you're asking halfway through, especially after the original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User startActivityForResult to start the EditActivity and use setResult the return the data.

Update the display in `onActivityResult` method which is triggered when the onResume is called in the Starting Activity. Make sure to check resultCode == RESULT_OK.